# VB.net/Asp.net loading a control programatically with a public property to be set

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls

I have a vb.net asp application where I'm loading a control (from another control on a page). I want to set a variable between the two controls when it loads.

This is where I load the control:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim AuditControl As Control = LoadControl("~/controls/auditcompanies.ascx")
        phCompanies.Controls.Add(AuditControl)
    End Sub
```

On the control that's being loaded i've exposed the item i want to change as a property

```
Public Property resultType() As String
        Get
            Return m_resultType
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_resultType = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Basically all it is doing is setting a parameter for my table adaptor

```
 Public Sub Load_Data()

        dtblog = New dsDECorp.ClientInfoDataTable
        dtblog = tablog.GetAudits(m_resultType)
        For Each rClient As dsDECorp.ClientInfoRow In dtblog

            CID = rClient.ClientID
            ClientName = rClient.CompanyName

        Next
        dtblog.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

How do I pass the parameter through the property from the first control to the second when it loads?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I'm confused... what is the first control and where is it?

Comment: The first control is on a aspx page, just has text etc in it but it loads the second control inside it

Answer (score 0):

I'm a C# guy so forgive me if I make any syntax errors but the following should work for you:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     Dim AuditControl As Control = LoadControl("~/controls/auditcompanies.ascx")
     Dim AuditControlType As Type = AuditControl.GetType()
     Dim AuditField As FieldInfo = AuditControlType.GetField("resultType")
     AuditField.SetValue(AuditControlType, "Your Value")
     phCompanies.Controls.Add(AuditControl)
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that - Wheres FieldInfo set? VB moans that it's not defined

Comment: Its part of the System.Reflection namespace

Comment: Try calling 'AuditControlType.GetFields()' to get all available fields and verify yours is available.